# How to config logging for celery flower?

Tags: logging, celery, config, flower

I have a few questions about celery flower that I can't seem to find in the docs.

1. how to specify the log path ... I literally can't find anything about this. Some predecessor of mine set up 'celery flower  -f /path/to/log' in the upstart script, but that doesn't work, and I can't find any doc referencing that method
2. authentication - the docs suggest '--basic_auth=user:pass' but I'd rather use a conf file, and putting 'basic_auth=user:pass' in conf file throws an error

Answer (score 3):

For your first question, if you are not using supervisor to run flower, you can add --log_file_prefix=/path/to/file.log when starting it (as stated in the --help file):

```
--log_file_prefix=PATH         Path prefix for log files. Note that if you
                               are running multiple tornado processes,
                               log_file_prefix must be different for each
                               of them (e.g. include the port number)
```

If you are using supervisor, then you should specify the log files inside the [program] section:

```
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/flower.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/flower.out.log
```